# M/G/$\infty$ queue with mixture of deterministic service times

Tags: queueing-theory

Hey guys I am studying queueing theory and I am trying to understand this problem. Consider an $M/GI/ \infty $ queue with the following service time distribution: the service time is $1/\mu_i$ with probabbility $p_i$, and $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i/\mu_i=1/\mu$. In other words the service time consists of a mixture of $K$ deterministic service times. I am trying to understand if the departure process of the model is Poisson? Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved that $M/GI/\infty$ queues for any general service time distribution is quasi-reversible, that is the departure process , $D(-\infty,t] $ is Poisson and is independent of the state of the system at time $t$, that is $X(t)$.
A very nice proof of this can be found in this paper : http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/physics.pdf